# having trouble with git merging

Tags: git

I am having some hardtime with understanding the right branching model.

So far from what I understood from [this manual](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is this:

Lets say I have a project with 10 commits already. Suddenly, I realised there is and latest correct commit was commit #8. So I checkout that commit, make a new branch (hotfix-1) and make some changes.
Lets say commit #10 style.css is color:blue; and commit #8 style.css color:pink. What I want to have is commit #11 style.css color:red;

So I make these changes in hotfix-1 branch, commit them, checkout to master and run git merge --no-ff bugfix-1.

But then there is an conflict to fix. on the line color. But of course there is an conflict, otherwise if I wouldnt change anything what would be the purpose of fixing a bug?

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is a merge conflict is because the line you changed in commit #11 was also changed on the master branch after the point you branched off at. If at commit #10 the style was still color:pink, as it was in commit #8, you would have no merge conflicts.

How it stands now, you'll just have to resolve the conflicts manually.

If you're new to Git, I found this interactive tutorial extremely helpful to wrap my head around branching and merging: http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/